# Добавление собственного Control в SceneBuilder (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Можно ли добавить собственный элемент управления в SceneBuilder, что бы кроме стандартных (например TextField) в списке было MyTextField?

Я попробовал использовать собственный MyTextField сопоставив его со стандартным TextField, но это неправильно:

Вот мой класс элемента управления:

```
public class MyTextField extends TextField{

    public MyTextField(MyVar var){

        // что-то новое
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

Вот контроллер:

```
public class FieldsController {

    @FXML
    MyTextField fld ;

    public FieldsController() {
        MyVar var = new MyVar("test");
        MyTextField fld = new MyTextField(var);
    }
}
```

Вот файл Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            //=====суть тут==================================================
            AnchorPane fields ;
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/FieldsView.fxml"));
            fields = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            FieldsController controller = loader.getController();
            //===============================================================

            Scene scene = new Scene(fields,1000,800);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Но получаю предупреждение в .fxml файле:

*You can not assign 'TextField' to the controller field 'MyTextField'*

И соответственно исключения во время компиляции

Comment: Сделать можно, JFoenix элементы вполне можно импортировать и использовать в билдере. Можете посмотреть как они организованы. Я обычно собственные элементы использовал в динамических блоках, поэтому в сцен билдере они мне не были нужны.А с наследованием все верно? Оно часто любит свинговые импорты подсовывать.

Comment: @Maxim , Ваш комментарий направил в нужную сторону. Вот пример как можно добавить собственный компонент в виде .jar файла в SceneBuilder:  <https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/adding-custom-javafx-component-to-scene-builder-2-0-part-2/>        С наследованием все верно.

Comment: @Maxim Можно подробнее про Ваш способ (в динамических блоках) ? Что имеется в виду?

Comment: Когда есть список объектов (например товары в магазине, красивая сложная строка таблицы и пр.) можно создать один свой составной контрол, передать туда объект с данными, заполнить его и добавить на сцену.

Comment: @Maxim То есть используя только Java/JavaFX код и не пользуясь FXML разметкой?